# Javascript events in html tag

Tags: javascript

When including JavaScript in a web page, why is it generally
considered poor
form to use the various inline event attributes

`(such as onclick, onsubmit,etc) in HTML tags? (e.g. <div onclick="dostuff()">Click Me</div>)`

Comment: Because generally you want to separate a pages: Function( JS ), Structure( HTML ), and Style( CSS ). That way everything is in one place.

Comment: It clutters up the html with javascript code. HTML is meant for layout not events. If you place your event handling information in a single place it's easier to maintain as well.

Comment: Apart from keeping content, styling and functionality separate it also about maintainability. If this is a 'one-off' function call then it will not cause any problems. If this is required on mulitiple elements across multiple pages, and you decide to change the function name, then you have a lot of editing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the arquitecture you want to implement in your application and the philosophy of the javascript framework you are using.

For example, when you use a lot of jQuery in your page, you could prefer to use an programatic way to register event handlers to your events, having your html clean of any behavior.

In other scenarios, you might want to use a framework like backbone, emberjs or angularjs which use html templates to automate and ease DOM manipulation. This approach prefers the declarative way to bind data and event handlers to DOM elements to avoid putting too much behavior in the javascript code.